# I can't able to use gem 'ar-octopus' in rails 6.0.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

it throws

```
ruby-2.7.1/gems/ar-octopus-0.10.2/lib/octopus/shard_tracking.rb: 23:in `alias_method': undefined method `any?' for class `ActiveRecord: :Associations: :CollectionAssociation' (NameError)
```

Answer (score 1):

To quote [the README.mkdn](https://github.com/thiagopradi/octopus/blob/2aa94684d4d6e4fa8a121b10896f99e879db61fe/README.mkdn) file of the `ar-octopus` gem:

> **Important Notice**
>
> Octopus will enter into maintainance mode once Rails 6 is released - since Rails 6 will include all the features for Database Sharding / Replication into Rails Core (PR: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/34052). Once the first version of Rails 6 beta is released, there will be a migration guide to help users migrate from Octopus to Rails 6.

It is thus likely that the gem does not support Rails 6 at all. Instead, you should use the multi-database capabilities built into Rails directly.